# How do I allow users to dial numbers in my tableView cells?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a table containing cells with phone numbers.  How can I allow the user to dial these numbers by tapping the cell? It's not working by default and there's no option in interface builder like there is for uiwebviews so I imagine I need to programmatically tell the app to dial the number when the cell is tapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a cell is selected your table view delegate will get sent a message `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. From there, you can use the `tel:` URI scheme to launch the phone app with the given phone number.